# How can I suggest a new exercise on Fitocracy?

Tags: fitocracy

The mods are always giving people the link but I can't find it on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the website, ignore the "Contact" tab and go down the left column to the "Useful Links" in small light gray text. "Suggest an exercise" is there.